# Parse html tags and markdown language in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

im trying to convert html content coming from an api call to text in react native. The html content contains a mixture of markdown language and html tags. Is there any solution to render both of the content types.

I've tried using react-native-render-html package but this doesnt render the markdown.
Then i"ve tried react-native-markdown-display but this doesnt render the html tags.

Here is a sample of the content coming from the api:

```
Object {
  "category": null,
  "content": "Kodi i Standardeve udhëhiqet nga 4 parime kryesore dhe 7 angazhime, që organizatat anëtare të Kodit të Standardeve do të duhet të përmbushin dhe zbatojnë në veprimtarinë e tyre të përditëshme.
Nëpërmjet një procesi vetëvlerësimi dhe reflektimi të bredshëm organizativ, bazuar në një tërësi treguesish të verifikueshëm e të përcaktuar në **Kornizën Vetëvlerësuese të Kodit të Standardeve**, organizatat do të mund vlerësojnë praktikat e tyre të tanishme dhe përputhshmërinë e tyre me parimet dhe angazhzimet në Kod.


Kodi është një praktikë mirëqeverisjeje e ngritur dhe bazuar në përvojën globale dhe rajonale mbi praktikat më të mira të standardeve sociale si ajo e [Global Accountability Standard](https://www.csostandard.org/) si dhe [Balkan Civil Society Development Network](https://www.balkancsd.net/bcsdn-adopts-a-code-of-conduct/) Code of Conduct. Bazuar në këto praktika, Kodi i Standardeve për OJF-të u punua dhe zhvillua më tej nga një grup prej [16 organizatash jofitimprurëse ](https://resourcecentre.al/sq/rritja-e-pergjegjshmerise-se-oshc-ve/) angazhuar vullnetarisht në këtë proces, duke e përshtatur sipas dinamikave të zhvillimit të sektorit në Shqipëri.


**Parimet që bashkojnë anëtarët e Kodit:**

1.  OJF-të anëtare të Kodit, si vlerë kryesore, kanë respektimin e të drejtave universale të njeriut dhe promovimin e barazisë gjinore.
2.  OJF-të anëtare të Kodit promovojnë dhe advokojnë për drejtësi dhe barazi.
3.  OJF-të anëtare të Kodit nxisin në të gjitha aspektet e punës së tyre, pjesëmarrjen aktive të qytetarëve të interesuar dhe komuniteteve vendore.
4.  OJF-të anëtare të Kodit tregojnë kujdes për mjedisin dhe zhvillimin e qëndrueshëm të tij.



**Organizatat anëtare të Kodit angazhohen për të qënë:**

1.  Organizata të hapura dhe transparente
2.  Organizata të orientuara drejt partneriteti
3.  Të qeverisura mirë
4.  Organizata me integritet organizativ
5.  Me financim, ngritje fondesh dhe manaxhim i burimeve në mënyrë Etike
6.  Me burime njerëzore të mirë menaxhuara dhe
7.  Advokues të përgjegjshëm



Njihu me gjerësisht me Kodit e Standardeve <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"
{apiURL}/uploads/KODI_I_STANDARDEVE_PER_ORGANIZATAT_JOFITIMPRURESE_NE_SHQIPERI_13874133f8.pdf\">këtu</a> <br>
Njihu me gjerësisht me Kornizën Vetëvlerësuese <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"
{apiURL}/uploads/Korniza_36fb2b5534.pdf\">këtu</a>
",
  "content_preview": "Kodi i Standardeve udhëhiqet nga 4 parime kryesore dhe 7 angazhime, që organizatat anëtare të Kodit të Standardeve do të duhet të përmbushin dhe zbatojnë në veprimtarinë e tyre të përditëshme.",
  "coverImageSubtitle": null,
  "coverImageTitle": null,
  "created_at": "2021-06-25T10:37:20.363Z",
  "custom_link": null,
  "gallery": Array [],
  "id": 16,
  "isDeleted": null,
  "locale": "sq",
  "localizations": Array [
    Object {
      "id": 17,
      "locale": "en",
      "published_at": "2021-06-25T10:38:12.831Z",
    },
```